# Python number of email attachements scalable

Tags: python, smtplib

I am sending an email for deliveries. The email will have attached all documents depending on how many things are on the truck. In the below code I will show what I have:

```
if filSize > 1:
        for u in range(filSize-1):
    
            att2 = ("C:\\Users\\hancke\\Desktop\\TEst mail\\" + filNameArr[z][2] + ".pdf", "application", "pdf", filNameArr[z][2] + ".pdf")
            att3 = (att3, att2)


        print("What to expect for att3:")
        print(att3.__str__())
        for attachment, main, sub, filename in (
            att3):
            with open(attachment, "rb") as fp: msg.add_attachment(fp.read(), maintype=main, subtype=sub,
                                                                      filename=filename)
        z = z + 1
    else:
        with open(attach1, "rb") as fp:
            msg.add_attachment(fp.read(), maintype="application", subtype="pdf", filename="filename.pdf")
```

This is the last thing that I have tried. When there is only one delivery everything is fine. With multiple deliveries having it static it will look like this:

```
for attachment, main, sub, filename in (
            ('C:\\Users\\hancke\\Desktop\\TEst mail\\151515.pdf", "application", "pdf", "PDFTest.pdf"'),
            ('C:\\Users\\hancke\\Desktop\\TEst mail\\202020.pdf", "application", "pdf", "PDFTest.pdf"'), 
            ('C:\\Users\\hancke\\Desktop\\TEst mail\\252525.pdf", "application", "pdf", "PDFTest.pdf"')):
            with open(attachment, "rb") as fp: msg.add_attachment(fp.read(), maintype=main, subtype=sub, filename=filename)
```

I am not sure how to change that static value so that it can scale on the amount of items out for delivery. I have tried a few different things, But cant seem to find the right way to solve this. Currently I have the  `att2 = ("C:\\Users\\hancke\\Desktop\\TEst mail\\" + filNameArr[z][2] + ".pdf", "application", "pdf", filNameArr[z][2] + ".pdf")`

`att3 = (att3, att2)`

With `att3` being my first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the round brackets in a for loop. If you do that the unpacking is only one item long. The dynamic list you want to use should be in the same format as how you want to unpack it. See [this](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-unpack-list/) for more info on packing/unpacking lists and tuples

```
my_dynamic_list = [(attachment, main, sub, filename)]
for attachment, main, sub, filename in my_dynamic_list:
        with open(attachment, "rb") as fp: msg.add_attachment(fp.read(), maintype=main, subtype=sub, filename=filename)
```

Furter, the `if .. else ..` is not on the same indent.